# more secure way to store username and password for openvpn

Tags: openvpn, passwd

I've set up an OpenVPN service on my server with username and password authentication and no clients' certificates needed.

I've set the username and password in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. now, it's OK to connect with a specific user for OpenVPN (which is *client1*), **but I've tried *root* (a linux user), it's also OK to be connected.**

The question is, is there anyway to store those users for OpenVPN instead of passwd? It's too dangerous I think, or other any group (create a group in /etc/gourp for OpenVPN) to limit them?

server.conf

```
port 20487
proto udp
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-crypt ta.key 0 # This file is secret
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-GCM
max-clients 24
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 5


explicit-exit-notify 1

plugin openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
verify-client-cert none
username-as-common-name
script-security 2
```

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [destnation] 20487
auth-user-pass
#verify-client-cert none
#username-as-common-name
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ca.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
ta.key
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

/etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
***
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
***
client1:x:1001:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

/etc/shadow

```
root:$y$*:19532:0:99999:7:::
***
nobody:*:19172:0:99999:7:::
***
client1:$y$j9T$K0ubESGFtXD2Imra5pMVJ/$ZUM2HNYn.0X9smrtKEAdgjIclQIdcURbI4xxlTU6tHB:19532:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `login` PAM stack; copy it and create your own. For example, `/etc/pam.d/openvpn`. Once you have a PAM stack separate from the system login configuration, you can customize it in various ways:

- e.g. you can insert a `pam_succeed_if.so` to avoid even *trying* authentication attempts if the user isn't in a specified group;
- you can replace `pam_unix.so` (the /etc/shadow check module) with `pam_pwdfile.so` which can in fact read a separate password-hash file; (note that pam_pwdfile is a separately installed module)
- you can keep the authentication part as-is but modify the *authorization* part, i.e. the `account` group, so that it rejects users who aren't in a specified group.

  (The `auth` stack verifies correctness of the supplied credentials, the `account` stack verifies validity of the account and permissions to access the service.)

For example:

```
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup vpnusers
auth requisite pam_unix.so
```